# Cannot disable a submit button using jQuery on Contact Form plugin (Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

The page is using jQuery v1.11.3, and I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Disabling submit button.");
    jQuery("#submitBtn").prop("disabled", true);
  });
</script>
```

Oddly enough, the console.log runs just fine - but the submit button never receives the 'disabled' attribute.

I have even tried using the following to make sure the ID was correct:

```
jQuery("#submitBtn").remove();
```

When I ran that code, the button did indeed go away.

Thinking it might be an older version of jQuery running, I also attempted the older jQuery method:

```
jQuery("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

but that didn't seem to work either.

The live URL of this page is: http://www.advancedpowderproducts.com/get-a-quote/

Anybody have any ideas as to what I am missing here?

Comment: As a side note, in the event that you're wondering why I am disabling the submit button - disabling the button is only the first step. They want to put some validation in to screen email addresses. So I want to default the submit button to be disabled, until the email address entered validates.

Comment: I ran your code in the browser console and it is disabling the submit button

Comment: I 100% agree that the code SHOULD work. I tested it as well in codepen. But - if you do a search for "disabled" in the inspector, you'll see that my jQuery code is in the source, and is not working, even though it should be. I say "it should be" somewhat with confidence, because the console.log code directly before it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run this from the console I see that I get the result you aspect.

```
$('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', true);
```

So probably the button is rendered after the execution of this line.
You can try executing with a bit of delay.

```
setTimeout(function (){
    $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', true);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You were absolutely right. Looks like it was taking a little bit of time for the submit button to render. The timeout did the trick. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Two code snippets I ran in the console of live URL you provided and both worked. I checked in the inspector too.

First (with click):

```
jQuery('#submitBtn').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Second (on load):

```
jQuery("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```